# Bootstrap - Images being stretched to width of div

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid of resized images (the original images are bigger than what would fit on the grid setup using Bootstrap.

I'm running into a problem where if I decrease the width of my window, instead of remaining the same resized size and responding to the smaller width, each image is being stretched (larger than its original size) to fit the width of the div.

Any help?

[image]
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 group">
      <h4>Unsorted Pictures</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><img src="../img/image.jpg" class="image"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rectangle {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.group {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;

  text-align: center;
}

.unsorted {
  height: 190px;
}

.image {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Container has a max-width of 1024px.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the minimum width declaration from the .image class.

```
.image {
    /* min-width: 100%; REMOVE THIS */
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Here is your markup with my solution in Bootply. Looks like it is working fine.

http://www.bootply.com/rx9NWTMq9f

Comment: Then there must be another declaration elsewhere that is causing your image class to have min-width:100% or maybe even a display:block. Do you have a link you can share?

Comment: I don't see anything there that might explain the issue, but this appears to only be a segment of the whole CSS. I would need to see all the CSS on the site, or better yet an example of the problem in a live environment, to properly diagnose the problem.

Comment: that's the entire css haha

Comment: Here is your markup in a live environment. I don't see the issue you described... http://www.bootply.com/rx9NWTMq9f

Comment: so the images start out in rows, but once i reduce the width of the screen, they break out of the rows and one image is shown at a time

is there no way to maintain the rows, so on smaller screen sizes there's just less images per row instead of only one image per row?

Comment: Change the col-md-1 to col-xs-1. But with that many columns (more than 12) inside a single row, it will still break out of the row because Bootstrap is a 12 column grid by default and you have more than 12 columns there, unless you customized your Bootstrap to have more than 12 columns. However, this issue really wasn't a part of the original question. Please mark an answer as the correct solution and ask another question if you have one rather than asking multiple questions in one.

Answer (score 0):

Your .image class has a dynamic width set that is percentage based.  It will always change based on it's container.

You have a couple options.

1. Remove `min-width: 100%;` this sets the image to the size of it's container.
2. Try changing it to a fixed measurement like pixels if you want it to remain static.

Comment: i removed min-width and its still being stretched. i want the rows of images to remain in rows for as long as possible but it's not happening